# document.queryselector returns null and I am unsure why

Tags: reactjs, jquery-selectors

This is in the front end of a react/js app. In my file called supplier container the following is part of my component Did Mount function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.supplier-data');
}
```

Then in the render method I call another file which calls another file which calls another file which has the following in its render method:

```
<tbody>
                        {this.props.data.map((dataItem, data_k) => (
                            <tr key={data_k} className={dataItem.deleted_at ? 'deleted-supplier' : null}>
                                {this.props.config.map((configItem, conf_k) => (
                                    <td key={` ${conf_k}-${data_k} `} className="align-middle supplier-data">
                                        {this.getValue(dataItem, configItem)}
                                    </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
```

Note the className = supplier-data in the td tag. I am trying to access the value from the getValue function which is as follows:

```
getValue(dataItem, configItem, defaultVal = 'N/A') {

    var value = null;

    if (configItem.content) {
        var value = this._getValueFromMethod(dataItem, configItem);
    }

    if (configItem.attribute && configItem.attribute.search(/\./) !== -1) {
        var value = this._getValueFromSegmentAttribute(dataItem, configItem)
    }

    if (configItem.attribute && configItem.attribute.search(/\./) == -1) {
        var value = this._getValueFromStaticAttribute(dataItem, configItem);
    }

    if (configItem.dateFormat && value) {
        value = moment(value).format(configItem.dateFormat);
    }

    return value || defaultVal;
}
```

The other functions in this are not important. When I console log element from componentDidMount above I get null. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a querySelector to get the element, you should use [React's ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)